# Are LP gains capped?

Tags: league-of-legends

Everyone knows that you start with 0 points in a division and you gain or lose more LP if your MMR is higher or lower than your current division.

Now I know it is possible to skip divisions, but if your mmr is really high, could you gain lets say +50 or even go directly to a promotion after just one win (would be +100)? Or is the LP gain capped at some point and you just skip let's say 2 divisions or something like that after a won promotion?

Comment: I do believe it is capped. They way it works is that if you have a higher mmr than your division, you gain extra lp, if you keep winning (further increasing the mmr/division difference), you will gain more lp per win. And after some point (we dont know the specific numbers) the system decides that you are to skip a division. from the majority of people I know that skipped, it is around 35 lp per win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I earned 50 LP maximum. I was in Plat1 while my MMR was around Dia2 players. I skipped 5->3, 3->1 every time. I do not think there is a cap in LP gains, but getting high numbers are really rare, they only usually happen when a player doesn't play for a couple of months resulting in league drops. I have friends that gained about 70.

I do not totally agree but, here is an interesting post:

> The cap is technically 100. It is rare, but some people skip divisions when their hidden MMR is much higher than their current placement. Therefore, skipping one division on your finishing promo game would net you 100 LP, and skipping multiple divisions would increase your LP gain by multiple hundreds.
>   So, say a challenger player makes a new account, and purposefully loses to get the account started in bronze 5. Each time he enters a promo series, he dodges games to drop back down into bronze 5, but his MMR doesn't suffer. The player continues to do so until he has an MMR of >3k. The player than wins his promo series, and is directly promoted to challenger. The increase to bronze 4 is +0LP, so that is negated. To bronze 3 is 100, bronze 2 is 200, 1 is 300, and the pattern continues.
>   The total increase would be a 2400 LP gain. I suppose this could be called the maximum.

http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3947302

Comment: Note that this specific method is no longer possible, since if your MMR is above your league by an entire tier, you will skip some promotion series until it's not anymore.